# Is defilement the reason why Jesus advised Mary to not touch him? John 20:17

Tags: jesus, law, purity-laws

John 20:17 Literal Standard Version, Jesus says to her,

> “Do not be touching Me, for I have not yet ascended to My Father; and
> be going on to My brothers, and say to them, I ascend to My Father and
> your Father, and [to] My God and your God.”

If defilement is the reason, what damage would it cause? If being touched by Mary is a trivial matter, why did Jesus advised her not to touch him?

In addition, would Jesus be sinning if he allows Mary to touch him? if not, why would he not allow Mary to touch him?

If Jesus was about to enter God's presence and came into contact with anything that was unclean, would he still be able to enter God's presence? Thus, my question.

The bible is a Jewish book after all and Jesus being a Jew, said he did not come to destroy the law but to fulfill it. Does Jesus refusal to be touched has a basis in laws pertaining to High Priests' entering God's presence?

Comment: @ Alex Balilo Upvoted your question. I confess I never gave this much scrutiny. Just taking this account at face value I assumed Jesus did not want Mary to touch him and that WHEN he ascended he would be somehow cleansed. Good luck picking a favorite answer on this one.

Answer (score 2):

It is not, in my opinion, a defilement issue. Both she and Jesus were prevented from completing their tasks because of her desire to cling to Him. She needed to go tell the others and her clinging wouldn't let her.

Other translations say: "Do not hold on to me", or "Do not cling to Me".

[John 20:17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2020%3A17&version=NKJV) New King James Version

> 17 Jesus said to her, “**Do not cling to Me**, for I have not yet ascended
> to My Father; but go to My brethren and say to them, ‘I am ascending
> to My Father and your Father, and to My God and your God.’ ”

[Thirdmill](https://thirdmill.org/answers/answer.asp/file/40485) says

> A little Greek can assist us. In the verse, "do not touch me" - me mou
> haptou - is employing what we call the present imperative tense. The
> present tense is used for **expressing continued action.** This then is a
> "prohibition," or STOP touching me. A prohibition in the present
> imperative demands that an action then in progress be stopped.

[John Calvin](https://thirdmill.org/answers/answer.asp/file/40485) explained:

> They fixed their attention on his bodily presence, and did not
> understand any other way of enjoying his society than by conversing
> with him on the earth. We ought, therefore, to conclude, that **they
> were not forbidden to touch him, until Christ saw that, by their
> foolish and unreasonable desire, they wished to keep him in the world.**

[Bibleref](https://www.bibleref.com/John/20/John-20-17.html) says:

> This response is to Mary Magdalene, who has just realized that the
> person speaking to her at Jesus' empty grave is Christ, Himself (John
> 20:11–16). **The term Jesus uses here is haptou, which implies a close,
> clutching action.** Later, Jesus will invite others to physically touch
> Him (John 20:27). So, **His meaning here does not seem to be that Mary
> should not contact Him, at all. It more likely means that she is not
> to stay there, or keep clinging to Him, but that she needs to go and
> tell the disciples what she has seen.**

[Ellicott's Commentary for English Readers](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/ellicott/john/20.htm)

> Touch me not; for I am not yet ascended to my Father.—The probable
> explanation of these words is to be found in the fact that **she had
> cast herself at His feet with the customary reverential embrace of the
> knees**, and perhaps to make doubly sure the fact that it was the Lord’s
> body, and that His words are meant to prevent this. The words
> themselves must be carefully considered. **“Touch” represents a Greek
> word which means to “cling to,” to “fasten on,” to “grasp” an object.**
> The tense is present, and the prohibition is, therefore, not of an
> individual act, but of a continuance of the act, of the habit, “Do not
> continue clinging to Me.” Her act supposed a condition which had not
> yet been accomplished. **He had not returned to earth to abide
> permanently with His disciples** in the presence of the Paraclete (comp.
> John 14:18), for He had not yet ascended to the Father. There should
> come a permanent closeness of union in His presence in the soul; but
> then the spirit which her act was manifesting was one which would
> prevent this presence. The coming of the Paraclete depended upon His
> going to the Father (comp. John 16:7), **but she would cling to a
> visible presence, and has not learnt the truth so hard to learn, “It
> is expedient for you that I go away” (John 16:7.)**

Answer (score 1):

The implication is that some special condition applied because Jesus had risen from the dead but had not yet ascended. Beyond that we have to speculate. Ritual purity should not be entirely ruled out. If Jesus sensed that Mary was menstruating, for example, he might not (depending on whether he observed the Torah law about this) want her to touch him during the time of his own preparation to ascend and meet God. (See Lev. 15:19)
This interpretation is supported by the fact that Jesus let himself be touched by Thomas during this period. Being touched by a man would not normally involved ritual defiling, but being touched by a menstruating woman would indeed do so.

The Jewish Annotated New Testament does not mention this possibility, but it does see a connection between this scene and a verse in the Song of Songs (3:4)

> Hardly had I left them
> when I found him whom my soul loves. I held him and would not let him go
> until I had brought him to my mother’s house,
> to the chamber of her who conceived me.

This seems to imply a romantic connection between Jesus and Magdalene, in which case Jesus would be warning Mary not to cling to him: she must take her place as a "bride of Christ" along with other believers after the Ascension and the coming of the Holy Spirt on Pentecost.

**Conclusion**: Assuming that Jesus still followed Torah law at this time, he would indeed be concerned that Mary (if she was menstruating) avoid touching him. This, however, is uncertain. The idea Jesus warned Mary not to cling him emotionally is more likely. The two ideas are not mutually exclusive.

---

NOTE: Because the gospels often show Jesus to be at odds with the Pharisees concerning Torah law, there is a tendency among some commentators to think he did not observe it. However, nearly all of the arguments between Jesus and the Pharisees concerned matters that were unsettled in the Law itself: healing on the Sabbath, handwashing before meals, fasting, the nature of the coming of Elijah and the Messiah, etc. The text of Leviticus 15, however, was quite clear and there is no record of Jesus having contradicted it.

Comment: Jesus invited Thomas to touch him on the 8th day, John 20:26-27. If the period to install a high priest is 7, Exodus 29:35, does not that give substance, that Jesus observed that part of the law sinc jews and Jesus always refer to "what is written in almost everything they do especially if it pertains to entering God's presence.

Comment: Gnosticism is against God's Word. Mary Magdalene was never a "wife of Christ", as Jesus never married and never had carnal intercourse. He was like a eunuch, being the holy virgin Son of God.

Answer (score 0):

**Was it a defilement issue?**

Not at all!

Immediately afterwards, when the women were going a **second time** to the Apostles’ place to inform them about the risen Jesus (***first time** they went to report the empty tomb*), the women met Jesus on the way:

> “and as they were going to tell His disciples, then behold, Jesus met
> them, saying, “Greetings!” And having come near, they **laid hold of
> His feet**, and worshiped Him.” (Matt 28:9; Literal Standard Version).

See, the women TOUCHED Jesus sometimes afterwards. If this was a defilement issue, Jesus would have prevented them from doing so. But this time He didn’t.

And we need to remember that this was much before Thomas, a man, touched the Lord!

So, it is clear that this was not a defilement issue at all!

**Why did Jesus tell Mary not to "hold on to" Him?**

Because, Jesus was the “Firstfruit” (1 Cor 15:20) of the firstfruits.

Because, that day was the Wave sheaf offering day!

**Explanation**

Representing Jesus’ First Coming, God gave certain Feasts starting in the first month of Nissan (our March-April). These are the Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread (UB) and Pentecost.

*[Representing Jesus’ Second Coming, God gave certain Feasts in the 7th month (our September-October). These are the Feast of Trumpets, Atonement Day and the Feast of Booths]*.

The Feast of UB spans 7 days. In these 7 days will come a Saturday Sabbath. “On the morrow of” this Saturday “Sabbath”, i.e., on early Sunday morning, the High Priest was to wave the first ever crop of that year, bundled into a sheaf before the LORD in the Temple in Jerusalem (Lev 23:10-11).

This sheaf is the first fruit of the first fruits reaped in that year. If my memory is correct (I don’t claim surety but I remember as having read somewhere) that this sheaf is considered to be a **holy** offering to the LORD, **to be touched only by the High Priest**. (Since I am not very sure about the touching part, someone can confirm this).

This **holy sheaf (the first of the first fruits) represents Jesus Christ**, the First fruit of the first fruits.

In the New Testament, Jesus Himself is the High Priest in the order of Melchizedek (Heb 6:20).

So, when Mary Magdalene first saw Jesus, He, as the High Priest, was about to present Himself as the First Sheaf before the Almighty God the Father exactly at the time the Jewish high priest was supposed to wave the sheaf in the Temple in Jerusalem!!!

Since the sheaf was holy and NOT to be touched by anyone, man or woman, except the high priest, Jesus as the First fruit was not to be touched by anyone , man or woman, **before** presented to the Holy Father (Heb 9:12)!!

This is the reason why Jesus prohibited Mary from touching Him.

But immediately afterwards, Jesus allowed all the women to catch hold of Him and worship. Later only, Thomas, a man, got a chance to touch Jesus!!

Comment: Is the high priest allowed to enter the Most holy compartment if he had contact with something considered unclean?

Comment: @AlexBalilo – (1) OT rituals are only “a shadow of coming good heavenly things” (Col 2:17, Heb 8:5, 10:1). (2) The resurrected Jesus has “overcome the world” of sins (John 16:33). Nothing can “defile” Him anymore (Heb 7:26) because He is the Spirit (2 Cor 3:17). He cleanses others (2 Pet 2:20). (3) Jesus didn’t allow Mary to touch Him not because He is the High Priest but because He is the Firstfruit.

Comment: Even if Mary touched Jesus, nothing could have happened because nothing could defile Jesus anymore. He is “undefiled” (Heb 7:26). But Jesus wanted to do everything in the proper way (Mat 3:15) and “always pleasing to His Father” (John 8:29). This is why He asked Mary not to touch Him till He presented Himself to the Father as the holy Firstfruit. Later Mary touched Him.

Comment: As for your specific question about the high priest in the OT, God had given provisions for him to take (Lev 4:3). Why? Because, God knew he was “surrounded with weakness” (Heb 5:2). He had to offer sacrifices for his own sins (Heb 5:3; 7:27).

Comment: @ Nephesh Roi: Just as a point of consideration. Jesus bore the sins of the whole world and all time . At what point was He sanctified. When he rose to newness of life perhaps ? I have never considered this much since if it is addressed, I must have missed it. Since nothing unclean is allowed in Heaven, when?

Comment: @RHPclass79 – According to Jesus, defilement or uncleanness is not external but internal; something that comes out of the minds (Mat 15:8). Unclean things are allowed in Heaven as we can see Satan in Heaven (Job 1:6). This is why I believe that nothing can defile God or Heaven. Jesus always remained sanctified except at the time when God put the sins of the entire humanity of all time on Him (2 Cor 5:21). He became a curse for us (Gal 3:13) and the account of sin was settled in His death (Rom 6:23). A new chapter was opened in resurrection (Rom 6:4; Rom 1:4).

Answer (score 0):

Is defilement the reason why Jesus advised Mary to not touch him? John 29:17

No, it is not defilement, for we read in Matthew chapter 28:1,5-9 that Jesus allowed other women to touch him. (Verse 9)

NASB 28:1,5-9
Jesus Is Risen!

28:1 Now after the Sabbath, as it began to dawn toward the first day of the week, Mary Magdalene and the other Mary came to look at the tomb.

Matthew 28:5-9
5 And the angel said to the women, “[a]Do not be afraid; for I know that you are looking for Jesus who has been crucified. 6 He is not here, for He has risen, just as He said. Come, see the place where He was lying. 7 And go quickly and tell His disciples that He has risen from the dead; and behold, He is going ahead of you to Galilee. There you will see Him; behold, I have told you.”8 And they left the tomb quickly with fear and great joy and ran to report to His disciples. 9 And behold, Jesus met them [b]and said, “[c]Rejoice!” **And they came up and took hold of His feet,** and worshiped Him.

John 20:17 NASB
17 Jesus *said to her, “Stop clinging to Me, for I have not yet ascended to the Father; but go to My brothers and say to them, ‘I am ascending to My Father and your Father, and My God and your God.’”

From Jesus' reaction,"Stop clinging to Me, for I have not yet ascended to the Father;" it is obvious that Mary thought  Jesus would ascend and will not be able to see Him again. He assured her that He was not leaving at the moment, but to go and tell his disciples of his resurrection.

Answer (score 0):

He allows others to be touched, like He did allow Thomas to touch Him (John 20:27), thus, it is to be excluded that He could imply any remote idea of ritualistic defilement in case of Mary. Even the rays of the physical sun are not defiled by being touched by the naked bodies of the worst of the sinners lying on a sandy beach, so how could the Creator of this very sun be sallied by a touch of anybody? An impossible idea.

Then what? Why does He tells Mary not to touch Him, saying that He has not yet ascended to the Father? I would venture this explanation a likeness of which I have also read somewhere in patristic literature: Mary wants to embrace Him as she did it always, habitually, but the Lord wants her to understand a difference: He is about to depart to the Father and this marks a decisive momentum in the history of mankind, for nobody will be henceforth able to see Him in a usual or worldly manner, but now a loftier, deeper, thoroughly Holy Spirit-guided relationship will start, which is a higher state of relationship, as Paul asserts: "though we have known Christ after the flesh, yet now henceforth know we him no more" (2 Cor. 5:16). Thus, He wants to teach Mary concerning that, prepare her for that.

The same He does with all His disciples after the resurrection: He does not stay with them for long, appears to them unexpectedly, does not sleep with them or walk with them to cities and villages in presence of the other people, but converses solely to them in a privacy; when He eats with them, it is not out of need, but pedagogically, to demonstrate that He has resurrected with the same body in which He lived and that the resurrection is real, not any sort of phantom.

Another, less theological, explanation is that He wants Mary to hurry up and tell His disciples about His resurrection, and "do not touch Me, for I haven't ascended yet to the Father" simply means that "now it is more appropriate for you not to delay and go to annunciate to My disciples My resurrection, as to embracing Me, you will have ample time for that, for I haven't yet ascended to the Father and will not for 40 days". Also plausible and not exclusive of the first one either.

Answer (score 0):

It's truly difficult for us to understand what they were going through at that moment. You had put your entire life on hold, including your livelihood.  You were CONVINCED that he was the Messiah. Now, you are in hiding wondering if you are next to be nailed to a cross.  Jesus was as dead as dead can be.  Your entire world is upside down.

Mary Magdalene is at the tomb Peter and the others had run to the tomb only Peter entered and found only the linin wrap and the head covering and no body.  Mary is just outside the tomb WEEPING. The men depart to go back to the room where they are hiding.  Mary is still outside the tomb, still weeping, and stands up (she was on the ground sobbing)  looks in the tomb, and sees 2 angels who ask her why she is weeping.  She replies saying Because they have taken away my Lord and I do not know where they have put him. She turns and sees Yeshua but does not recognize him and he says to her Woman why are you weeping?
Mary says to him Sir, if you have carried Him away, tell me where you put Him, and I will take Him away.”

One can not read those words and not recognize just how much Mary loved Christ.  Yeshua said to her "Mary" and she saw him and said "Rabboni!" (Teacher)  The text does not say this but her instincts would have driven her to CLING TO HIM in her Joy and excitement that he was ALIVE!!  So much so that he had to say to her "Stop clinging to Me, for I have not yet ascended to the Father; but go to My brothers and say to them, "I am ascending to My Father and your Father, and My God and your God."

She immediately went back to the apostles to tell them what Yeshua directed her to say.

The other thing to keep in mind is that Physical contact between a man and a woman who are not married was not allowed culturally.